# Compilation fail when tried to execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
./node_modules/@arcgis/core/core/Message.js 11:17
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:17)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     if ("" === s) return "$";
|     const n = t(s, r),
>           i = n ?? "";
|     if (void 0 === i) throw new Error(`could not find key "${s}" in template`);
|     return i.toString();
```

got this error, dont know to resolve

Comment: Your NodeJS version is too old. The `??` operator requires at least v14

Comment: PS D:\MyFolder\new\VS_train\webapplication> node -v    
v18.12.0
but the version displayed here is above 14 !!